# Scratch equals operator problems

Tags: mit-scratch

I am using scratch.mit.edu version 2.0 on the internet and writing a program to evaluate a postfix expression. As I iterate through the input string such as: **"23+"** (postfix) letter by letter using the **letter..of...block**, it works fine.

I then add a **letter.. of..** block to identify a spacebar character so the user can insert blanks in the expression eg **"2      3          +"**

However, there seems no way to recognize **a blank** character. I tried

```
1) Lookahead = ""
2) Lookahead =' '  
3) Lookahead =''
```

None of which pick up that a space has been encountered.

Here is the project: https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/77653712/

Answer (score 5):

In Scratch, the box *is* the string literal - no quotes, unless you're looking for literal quotes. Just put a space in the box.

Just set it to check `<(Lookahead) = [ ]>`: (brackets are the symbol for the box)

[image: screenshot of script]

(That black line is me pressing ctrl+a to highlight and show that it exists.)

Comment: I tried typing in lookahead =[ ] and it did not pick up any spaces from the user using the spacebar. The same error occured/

Comment: I looked at what you did now. No brackets - just the space. Absolutely nothing else. The brackets in the post were my way of showing the syntax.

Comment: Yes just solved it and noticed you have added the same comment!

Comment: I clarified the answer to make the intention clear. If it was you who downvoted, i would appreciate if you would undo that.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I have found the solution. There is no character to represent a blank. You simply press space bar once!

[image]

You can see the letter nextChar of blanks is an **empty space** but, you must **add space using the spacebar** for it to work!!